# OpenLDAP as a Proxy cache only, no local database

Tags: caching, proxy, openldap

I am trying to get a local LDAP proxy cache running. The idea is this:

- Currently a computer `(A)` is sending all ldap requests to a remote ldap server `(L)`
- Instead of that, there should be a proxy cache "server" running on `A` to act as an intermediate between `A` and `L`. The cache would store all queries and all their attributes (until it is filled up and then it starts "recycling").

[OpenLDAP's Proxy Cache Engine](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html) looks pretty good, but there is not much information about how to set it up. There is an example config file, but I cannot get it to work.

When connected to the internet, running this command will successfully bind me.

```
ldapwhoami -vvv -h localhost -D "CN=Melka Martin,OU=something,OU=else,(...),DC=int,DC=somedomain,DC=com" -x -w <passwd>
```

However, each following request will still pool the remote LDAP server (as shown by sniffing the connection, and when the machine is disconnected from the internet, the local bind fails).

In the `slapd` output there is a lot of stuff, but the elligible:

```
56449abd QUERY NOT ANSWERABLE
56449abd QUERY CACHEABLE
```

This is the current config file, which should cache all the bind requests

```
database        ldap
suffix          "dc=int,dc=somedomain,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=admin,dc=int,dc=somedomain,dc=com"
rootpw          <something>
uri             ldap://dc-04.int.somedomain.com:389

overlay pcache
pcache         hdb 100000 1 1000 100
pcacheAttrset  0 *
pcacheTemplate (sn=) 0 3600
pcacheBind (sn=) 0 3600 sub dc=int,dc=somedomain,dc=com

cachesize 200
directory /var/lib/ldap
index       objectClass eq
index       cn eq,sub
```

I have created the `/var/lib/ldap` directory, added a default `DB_CONFIG` file in there and then edited the `slapd.conf` file. If there are more things to do to set it up properly, could you instruct me?

I am a little confused about the `rootdn`/`rootpw` directives. They are used to write into the remote LDAP server, correct?

---

---

**Edit: Below here is the original issue, which was resolved by using the full proper DN.**

As this is supposed to only be a proxy cache, I shouldn't need to set up a local database. So the config file looks like this:

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

moduleload pcache.la

database        ldap
suffix          "dc=int,dc=somedomain,dc=com"
rootdn          "dc=int,dc=somedomain,dc=com"
uri             ldap://dc-04.int.somedomain.com:389

overlay pcache
pcache         hdb 100000 1 1000 100
pcacheAttrset  0 *
pcacheTemplate (sn=) 0 3600

cachesize 20
directory /var/lib/ldap
index       objectClass eq
index       cn eq,sub
```

Now I would expect that any request to ldap://localhost would mirror to the remote LDAP, if not in the cache.

I use this command to test the auth on the remote server:

```
ldapwhoami -vvv -h dc-04.int.somedomain.com -p 389 -D melka@somedomain.com -x -w <passwd>
```

Which works well, I get the auth.

However, when I try to run the same command on localhost:

```
ldapwhoami -vvv -h localhost -p 389 -D melka@somedomain.com -x -w <passwd>
```

It fails, saying

```
ldap_initialize( ldap://localhost:389 )
ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34)
    additional info: invalid DN
```

Slapd is listening on localhost, netstat contains this line:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:389                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      10352/slapd
```

Is there something I am missing? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
melka@somedomain.com
```

That may be a DN in the target LDAP system, who knows, but it certainly isn't in OpenLDAP. You need to provide a proper Distinguished Name.

Comment: You are right. I used the full DN to successfully auth. However, the cache does not seem to be caching properly, because with every request, slapd connects to the remote LDAP server. Any ideas for that?

Comment: @MartinMelka have you found solution?

Comment: No, I gave up long time ago, unfortunately